# Texlive installation and revtex4-2: Why the error in Texlive is different from Texstudio

Tags: texlive

I wrote a manuscript using  `revtex4-2` in Texstudio. I got some underfull, overfull and two stuck float warnings. When I upload this manuscript in aps website it can not produce the pdf output! I merge the bbl file in the manuscript but nothing happened.  I try to install Texlive (apparently, my file has error in aps that runs in the TexLive), but in  the middle of the downloading it was interrupted (due to one error that unfortunately I could not see it). Now, I have some questions and I really appreciate any help. Is there any methods to resume the TexLive download? Can running in the textlive help me in this case? Additionally, I attached the log file that aps sent it to me, why  I did not  get  some errors in textstudio and how I can fix it. This manuscript includes 21 figures that I got 2 stack float errors (I could not get rid of it).  I checked some reported errors, but it was not true.

```
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**aipsamp.tex
(./aipsamp.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-2.cls
Document Class: revtex4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for
 documentation)
 Copyright (c) 2019 American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>
 Version (4.2d,4.2e): Modified by Mark Doyle and Phelype Oleinik
 .
ltxutil[2020/10/03 4.2e utilities package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter 
web at superscript.com)]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@centercr on input line 356.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray on input line 406.
\eqncolsep=\skip47
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing hyperref-unfriendly LaTeX definition of \mpfoot
note on input line 481.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 803.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count175
\@tbpen=\count176
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box47
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1834.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Making \typeout \long on input line 2099.
ltxfront[2020/10/03 4.2e frontmatter package (AO,DPC,MD)]
\c@affil=\count177
\c@collab=\count178
\absbox=\box48
ltxgrid[2020/10/03 4.2e page grid package (portions licensed from W. E. Baxter 
web at superscript.com)]
\c@linecount=\count179
\output@latex=\toks15
\box@size@1=\box49
\box@size@2=\box50
\@protection@box=\box51
\@topmark@saved=\toks16
\footins@saved=\box52
\footins@recovered=\box53
\column@recovered=\box54
\pagesofar=\box55
\footsofar=\box56
\pagegrid@col=\count180
Class revtex4-2 Info: Overriding \@vspace, \@vspacer, \@no@pgbk, \@newline, and
 \\  on input line 5665.
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\c@figure=\count187
\fbox@1=\box57
\c@table=\count188
\fbox@2=\box58
\c@video=\count189
\fbox@4=\box59
\@bibdataout=\write3
\widetext@top=\box60
\widetext@bot=\box61
Class revtex4-2 Info: Selecting society aps on input line 7658.
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps4-2.rtx
File: aps4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentatio
n)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX society APS selected on input line 40.
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Selecting aps on input line 7660.
Class revtex4-2 Info: APS journal aps selected on input line 7661.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps10pt4-2.rtx
File: aps10pt4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for document
ation)
Class revtex4-2 Info: RevTeX pointsize 10pt selected on input line 39.
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip50
\bibsep=\skip51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count190
)
Class revtex4-2 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7665.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revsymb4-2.sty
Package: revsymb4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for docum
entation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 128.
))
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 105.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen138
\Gin@req@width=\dimen139
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty
Package: times 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (SPQR) 
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty
Package: bbm 1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbbm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/bbm/m/n --> U/bbm/bx/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbbmss' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/bbmss/m/n --> U/bbmss/bx/n on input line 35.
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frak on input line 111.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bbb on input line 113.
))
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\ex@=\dimen140
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \text on input line 28.
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen141
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count191
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count192
\leftroot@=\count193
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count194
\DOTSCASE@=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box62
\strutbox@=\box63
\big@size=\dimen142
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count196
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count197
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count198
\dspbrk@lvl=\count199
\tag@help=\toks20
\row@=\count266
\column@=\count267
\maxfields@=\count268
\andhelp@=\toks21
\eqnshift@=\dimen143
\alignsep@=\dimen144
\tagshift@=\dimen145
\tagwidth@=\dimen146
\totwidth@=\dimen147
\lineht@=\dimen148
\@envbody=\toks22
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks23
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty
Package: bm 2019/07/24 v1.2d Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup6
\symboldletters=\mathgroup7
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 141.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 209.
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty
Package: mathrsfs 1996/01/01 Math RSFS package v1.0 (jk)
\symrsfs=\mathgroup9
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 147.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def
File: dvipsnam.def 2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cancel/cancel.sty
Package: cancel 2013/04/12 v2.2 Cancel math terms
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen149
\Hy@linkcounter=\count269
\Hy@pagecounter=\count270

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count271
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4717.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \href on input line 4987.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count272
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen150

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count273
\Field@Width=\dimen151
\Fld@charsize=\dimen152
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count274
\c@Item=\count275
\c@Hfootnote=\count276
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
File: hdvips.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for dvips

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
File: pdfmark.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials


Package hyperref Warning: You have enabled option `breaklinks'.
(hyperref)                But driver `hdvips.def' does not suppport this.
(hyperref)                Expect trouble with the link areas of broken links.

\pdf@docset=\toks24
\pdf@box=\box64
\pdf@toks=\toks25
\pdf@defaulttoks=\toks26
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count277
\Fld@listcount=\count278
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count279
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip55
))
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
Package: adjustbox 2020/08/19 v1.3 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks27
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks28
)
\XKV@depth=\count280
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty
Package: adjcalc 2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back
-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
Package: trimclip 2020/08/19 v1.2 Trim and clip general TeX material

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty
Package: collectbox 2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
\collectedbox=\box65
)
\tc@llx=\dimen153
\tc@lly=\dimen154
\tc@urx=\dimen155
\tc@ury=\dimen156
Package trimclip Info: Using driver 'tc-dvips.def'.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-dvips.def
File: tc-dvips.def 2019/01/04 v2.2 Clipping driver for dvips
))
\adjbox@Width=\dimen157
..

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty
Package: ifoddpage 2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
\c@checkoddpage=\count281
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty
Package: varwidth 2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
\@vwid@box=\box66
\sift@deathcycles=\count282
))
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen167
\ar@mcellbox=\box67
\extrarowheight=\dimen168
\NC@list=\toks29
\extratabsurround=\skip56
\backup@length=\skip57
\ar@cellbox=\box68
)
\TX@col@width=\dimen169
\TX@old@table=\dimen170

)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabulary/tabulary.sty
Package: tabulary 2014/06/11 v0.10 tabulary package (DPC)
\TY@count=\count284
\TY@linewidth=\dimen174
\tymin=\dimen175
\tymax=\dimen176
\TY@tablewidth=\dimen177
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
Package: subfig 2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2020/09/17 v2.1b caption3 kernel (AR)
\captionmargin=\dimen178
...
Package caption Info: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)             standard defaults will be used.
Package caption Info: \@makecaption = \long macro:#1#2->\par \vskip \abovecapti
onskip \begingroup \small \rmfamily \sbox \@tempboxa {\let \\\heading@cr \@make
@capt@title {#1}{#2}}\@ifdim {\wd \@tempboxa >\hsize }{\begingroup \samepage \f
lushing \let \footnote \@footnotemark@gobble \@make@capt@title {#1}{#2}\par \en
dgroup }{\global \@minipagefalse \hb@xt@ \hsize {\hfil \unhbox \@tempboxa \hfil
 }}\endgroup \vskip \belowcaptionskip  on input line 1120.
)
\c@KVtest=\count285
..
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty
Package: dcolumn 2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen186
\lightrulewidth=\dimen187
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen188
\belowrulesep=\dimen189
\belowbottomsep=\dimen190
\aboverulesep=\dimen191
\abovetopsep=\dimen192
\cmidrulesep=\dimen193
\cmidrulekern=\dimen194
\defaultaddspace=\dimen195
\@cmidla=\count292
\@cmidlb=\count293
\@aboverulesep=\dimen196
\@belowrulesep=\dimen197
\@thisruleclass=\count294
\@lastruleclass=\count295
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen198
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty
Package: nicefrac 1998/08/04 v0.9b Nice fractions
\L@UnitsRaiseDisplaystyle=\skip63
\L@UnitsRaiseTextstyle=\skip64
\L@UnitsRaiseScriptstyle=\skip65

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
))







Class revtex4-2 Info: Unrecognized array package. Please update this document c
lass! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 31.
Class revtex4-2 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 31.

1.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
) (./aipsamp.aux)
\openout1 = `aipsamp.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 31.

Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 31.

(
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count326
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 31.

(./aipsamp.out) (./aipsamp.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `aipsamp.out'.

Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: subfig package v1.3 is loaded.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
File: siunitx-abbreviations.cfg 2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
)
(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dictionary-
English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
) ABD: EverySelectfont initializing macros
LaTeX Info: Redefining \selectfont on input line 31.
\symgns@font=\mathgroup10
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `gns@font' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TS1/ptm/m/n --> TS1/ptm/b/n on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Math companion symbols declared on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \degree on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \celsius on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Using text companion symbols for \degree, \celsius and \p
erthousand on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ohm on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Using \textohm for \ohm on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \micro on input line 31.
Package gensymb Info: Using \textmu for \micro on input line 31.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Taking \maketitle back from hyperref on input line 31.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Overriding lineo.sty, restoring output routine, on input 
line 31.
Class revtex4-2 Info: Line numbering not turned on yet on input line 31.
\openout3 = `aipsampNotes.bib'.

Class revtex4-2 Info: Overriding \@LN@LLerror on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 31.


(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 31.


(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+rsfs on input line 31
.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd
File: ursfs.fd 1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+ptm on input line 3
1.

(/aps/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1ptm.fd
File: ts1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for TS1/ptm.
)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `BB84' on page 1 undefined on input line 58.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `GG02' on page 1 undefined on input line 58.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `GG02' on page 1 undefined on input line 62.

File: fig1.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<fig1.eps>

.....
73
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Agrawal' on page 3 undefined on input line 82
.


Package .....
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \unit 
                      
l.106       $\lambda$   &  1550            & $\unit
                                             {nm}$ \\
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
! Undefined control sequence.
l.108 ...          &  $4.7\times 10^{-5}$  & \unit
                                                  {(ns)^{-1}}\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.108 ...    &  $4.7\times 10^{-5}$  & \unit{(ns)^
                                                  {-1}}\\
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.108 ...  $4.7\times 10^{-5}$  & \unit{(ns)^{-1}}
                                                  \\
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.109       \midrule
                
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<inserted text> 
                
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.





                
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13473 strings out of 479918
 235786 string characters out of 5885701
 564869 words of memory out of 5000000
 29756 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558345 words of font info for 108 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,16n,115p,23403b,779s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on aipsamp.dvi (3 pages, 32584 bytes).
```

and:

```
\usepackage{graphicx,times,bbm,amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,bm,hyperref,mathrsfs,color,cancel}
\pdfminorversion=7
\usepackage{adjustbox}%,makecell
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[caption=false, justification=centerlast]{subfig}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\raggedright}{}{}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\newcommand{\acot}{\cot^{-1}}
\begin{document}    
    \preprint{AIP/123-QED}
    \title[Sample title]{a new method}  
\author{}
\affiliation{}
    \begin{abstract} 
    \end{abstract}
    \keywords{}
    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:introduction}

\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%
    
    \end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: the siunitx is probably too old and doesn't know \unit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  \unit is one of the siunitx commands.  Is it possible the aps texlive can not know siunitx?As I know they use 2017 version. Thank you for your comment

Comment: \unit is new in siunitx 3, in siunitx 2 it was called differently.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I did not determine the version of the siunitx. How do I realize that what version is used?